# Base class for pytest's tests

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I want to create base class with tests. I have same tests for different endpoints, but it depends on model, url, etc.

I've created TestBase class as below, with some methods, and defined class's attrs.

```
 class TestBase(Generic[Table]):     
    base_url: str = "some_url"      
    json_key: str = ""      
    model: Type[Table] = None       

    @pytest.mark.asyncio     
    async def test_get(self,
         /* fixtures */
     ):
         /* some test logic */
```

Then I inherit:

```
class TestBrand(TestBase[Brand]):
    base_url = "/brand"
    json_key = "brands"
    model = Brand
```

When I ran `pytest` - pytest run test from TestBase not from TestBrand.

Is there any opportunity to solve it?

I expect when I inherit TestBase, for example, TestBrand(TestBase) pytest will take TestBrand's attrs and with these attrs. will run all tests declared in TestBase.